# UTF-8 problems on php site

Tags: php, utf-8

i have little php site. I add to header this;

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

but still site doesn't show some UTF-8 characters here is example

http://tmd2.org/sozluk/?aksiyon=ara&terimId=4759

> altb�l�m

what can i do ?

Comment: Make sure the PHP script, and all other included scripts as well, are UTF-8 encoded (UTF-8 without BOM) as well. With Notepad++ (Windows) you could even convert an existing ANSI script to a UTF-8 script.

Comment: And also you should check your db's collation if you are fetching your data from a db

Comment: You're telling your browser to interpret your page in UTF-8. **But is it actually UTF-8?!** (Hint: no, it isn't.)

Comment: Actually i don't understand php so much i just modified html and css. Because i can't understand ho did this all what you said :)

Comment: @CihanZengin You should change your files to actually be encoded in UTF-8. This can be done with a number of tools (but shouldn't be done by manually replacing stuff with a text editor, as the ‘answer’ below suggests); your favourite search engine could help you find one.

Comment: Most likely you simply need to *save the file(s) in UTF-8 in your text editor that you're using to edit the files.*

Comment: yes. I saved all files with save as with encoding utf-8 but nothing changed

Comment: You say below in a comment that the content actually comes from a database. **Have you read the duplicate** which talks about this at length?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**i opened your web site http://tmd2.org/sozluk/?aksiyon=ara&terimId=4759**

i think ,you need set your editor encoding to UTF-8,for example,use "sublime text" or "windows notebook",open your script ,find the wrong code and replace it!

```js
<td width="98%"><strong>1-</strong> altb�l�m <font size="1px">
```

Comment: how ? i don't understand

Comment: I opened this file ( ara.php ) and with sublime text save with encoding UTF-8 but nothing changed

Comment: "altb�l�m" taken from the database or write in your php file?

Comment: then , don't forget set charset like :mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");

Comment: Well done. thank you so much :)

Comment: ok,don't forget choice is the best answer :)